# Vis js - Avoid edge overlap

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am using vis js v5 for one of my projects and i have a scenario where i have thousands of nodes with thousands of edges between them. The edges are not unique ie there could be multiple edges between the same node.

By default, vis js is aggregating the edges and displaying only one edge as shown below

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3ekg9hy/)

I am currently just using the default configs as follows

```
    var options = { 
       layout:{ 
        hierarchical:true
       },
        physics:{ 
         enabled:false;
       }
};
```

So my question is, is there any way all the edges could be drawn to make sure all edges are visible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
    physics: {
        barnesHut: {
            "gravitationalConstant": -3900,
            "centralGravity": 0
        },
        minVelocity: 1
    },
    autoResize: true,
}
```

Try this, if it works do verify my answer

If not then I can provide the full options that I used in my projects, and the edges don't overlap with each other.

Do let me know if you have any other query, will be happy to help you.